# Bloquear digitação campo TextBox com CalendarExtender

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

Boa tarde, preciso bloquear a digitação da data em um campo TextBox asp.net. O mesmo só poderá receber a data selecionada no componente calenarExtender aplicado ao TextBox. Alguém teria alguma forma via front end de bloquear a digitação?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem algumas opções, pode usar o `ReadOnly="true"`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
```

ou

```
txtDate.Attributes.Add("readOnly", "readonly");
```

ou via JQuery

```
$('#txtDate').attr("readonly", true);
```

O CalendarExtender continua funcionando e selecionando a data.